# Bindear una propiedad a un request en typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

soy nuevo en typescript estoy tratando de bindear un objeto con todas la propiedades de un usuario a un request,
este objeto es un payload el cual obtiene los datos de una decodificación de token.

esto para obtener el id del usuario logeado por el request

**bindear**

`req.user = this.payload;`

**codigo donde se agrega la pripiedad al req**

```js
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
import moment from 'moment';
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
import * as core from "express-serve-static-core";


const secret = 'clave_cecreta_analisis2_red_social';
//asegurar la autenticacion

exports.ensureAuth = function (req, res, next){
    const token = req.headers["authorization"]//almacenar datos req.headers en token y validar
    console.log('TOKEN ==> ' + token);
    if(!token){
        return res.status(403).send({ message: 'La peticion no tiene la cabecera de autenticacion'});
    }

    const tokenRep = token.replace(/['"]+/g, ''); //almacenar token en una varaible y limiarlo de comias 

    try{
        const payload = jwt.decode(token, secret); // Decodificar el token
        
        if(payload.exp <= moment().unix()){ //validar fecha de expiracion token
            return res.status(401).send({ message: 'El token a expirado'});
        }
    } catch(ex){
        return res.status(404).send({ message: ' El token no es valido'});
    }

    req.user = this.payload;

    
    next();
}
```

**Error**

```js
function getUsers(req: Request, res: Response){
  const identity = req.user.sub;
}
```

```
src/controllers/userController.ts:126:24 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

126   const identity = req.user.sub;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si trabajas con TypeScript debes de “decirle” al compilador que el objeto `request` del router tiene una propiedad llamada `user`.

```
// types.ts
import { Request } from “express”

interface User {
  // propiedades que tendrás disponibles 
}
  
export interface AuthRequest extends Request {
  user: User;
}
```

Luego, en tu controller específicas que `req` será de tipo `AuthRequest`:

```
function getUsers(req: AuthRequest, res: Response){
  const identity = req.user.sub;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar la fusion de tipos [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

TypeScript permite la fusión entre varios tipos, como interfaz con interfaz, enumeración con enumeración, espacio de nombres con espacio de nombres, etc. Una fusión notable que no está permitida es la fusión de clase con clase.

puedes crear una archivo que contenga la definicion de tipos como la siguiente

**express.merge.d.ts**

```
import 'express';
import JwtPayload from './jwt-payload.ts'


declare module 'express' {
  export interface Request {
    user: JwtPayload;
  }
}
```

**jwt-payload.ts**

```
export default interface JwtPayload {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  fullname: string;
  email: string;
  roles: Array<string>;
}
```